# python opencv live camera feed, scale object

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I have the following code for recognize objects/symbols.
My question is how can i improve my code for recognize objects when they are closer or further away?
Lets say I load a symbol and I need to recognize it at different ranges.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#symbool inladen
symbool = cv2.imread('klaver.jpg',0)
w, h = symbool.shape[::-1]

while(1):

    res, frame = cap.read()
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,symbool,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    threshold = 0.9
    loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
       # print "hallo"
        cv2.rectangle(img_gray, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 1)
    cv2.imshow('Resultaat', img_gray)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Updated :**

I have tried the tutorial below and came up with the following.
The problem is recognize the object, this method is drawing random rectangles and doesnt focus on the object/symbol it self

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

#Camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#symbool inladen
symbool = cv2.imread('klaver.jpg',0)
w, h = symbool.shape[::-1]

while(1):

    res, frame = cap.read()
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    found = None
    #res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,symbool,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:

            resized = imutils.resize(img_gray, width = int(img_gray.shape[1] * scale))
            r = img_gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

            if resized.shape[0] < h or resized.shape[1] < w:
                break

            edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
            result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, symbool, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

            clone = np.dstack([edged, edged, edged])
            cv2.rectangle(clone, (maxLoc[0], maxLoc[1]),
            (maxLoc[0] + w, maxLoc[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
                    found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)

    (_, maxLoc, r) = found
    (startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
    (endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + w) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + h) * r))


    threshold = 0.9
    loc = np.where( result >= threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
       # print "hallo"
       # cv2.rectangle(img_gray, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 1)
        cv2.rectangle(img_gray, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 255, 255), 1)
    cv2.imshow('Resultaat', img_gray)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to work within your same framework is to implement a pyramid approach. Simply load the image (or template) at multiple resolutions and loop over those. This is a great guide with Python+OpenCV code: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/

This method is to provide *scale invariant* template matching. You can get more robust with using feature detection (keypoints) which allows you to do scale and rotation invariance for your template. See http://robocv.blogspot.com/2012/02/real-time-object-detection-in-opencv.html for an example using SURF.

---

Edited in response to OP's comment below!

To address your second code snippet, there are a few issues, but you were closer than you probably thought!

1. It's using the Canny edges for the video frames, but not for the template. Should do Canny for both, or none. In the example he uses Canny, which is great for finding a text logo, but not so great if your template is a basic shape which shows up everywhere. E.g., I drew a plus sign on paper to use as a template and it wanted to select every corner in my image, too. Using just the regular images, not edge images, worked better for my template.
2. You're still using `loc = np.where(result >= threshold)`, but you already have the max values and their corresponding locations stored in `found`. All you need to do is draw a box whenever `maxVal >= threshold`.
3. Your threshold is way too high for this task. You should not expect a 90% match when the template could be at any scale and you're only computing a few discrete scales, especially since your template probably won't be perfectly straight every time.

---

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#symbool inladen
symbool = cv2.imread('klaver.jpg',0)
w, h = symbool.shape[::-1]

while(1):

    res, frame = cap.read()
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    found = None
    #res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,symbool,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:

            resized = cv2.resize(img_gray, None, fx=scale, fy=scale)
            r = img_gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

            if resized.shape[0] < h or resized.shape[1] < w:
                break

            result = cv2.matchTemplate(resized, symbool, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

            if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
                    found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)

    (maxVal, maxLoc, r) = found
    (startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
    (endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + w) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + h) * r))


    threshold = 0.5
    if maxVal >= threshold: 
       cv2.rectangle(img_gray, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 255, 255), 1)
    cv2.imshow('Resultaat', img_gray)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        print(maxVal)
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have updated my post. Do have some suggestions? The surf method isnt gonna work for me because i cant install it

Comment: This method uses the Canny edge detector and matches the edge maps of your image and template. However, you haven't created the edge map of your template, only your video frames! Take a look again at the first few lines of code in the tutorial :)

However, Canny is particularly well suited to the Call of Duty example, but you might have better luck with your original images. I got your code to work, and I'll post it back on my original answer.

Comment: @P.B, here's two examples running the code in the answer: [farther template](http://imgur.com/J7zCpBE), [nearer template](http://imgur.com/X54Sr9o).

Comment: We still need put the threshold to 0.8 to only detect the object that we need. Thanks for your reply and answer. It works. @Alexander Reynolds

Comment: Reynold, I got another question maby u can help me.
symbool = cv2.imread('klaver.jpg',0) this is for one template, I want to load 4 templates in here to detect them. Any ideas?

Comment: @P.B The easiest way with your same algorithm would be to loop over all templates. I would suggest opening up a new question if you can't figure it out, but I think you can do it!

Comment: Thanks I figured it out with the way u suggested. @Alexander Reynolds